# Chartist on click function without jQuery

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I am trying to get a simple function to trigger after I click on a data point on a line graph in Chartist with the following code:

```
chart.on('draw', function(data) {
    if(data.type === 'point') {
        data.element._node.onclick =  click(data)
    }
});
```

Nothing seems to occur, can anyone figure out why this does not work?

The click function works fine if called without the click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `click(data)`? The function that should be called on click? when yes then you did it wrong. You have to assign a function to a click handler:

```
chart.on('draw', function(data) {
    if(data.type === 'point') {
        data.element._node.onclick = event => click(data);
    }
});
```